# What was the largest strike, by % of a country's population, in history?

Tags: labour-history

This week, India had an *enormous* strike - up to 200 million people. Some links:

[Indian Workers Strike in Fight for Higher Wages(Guardian)](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/sep/02/indian-workers-strike-in-fight-for-higher-wages)

[Millions Indian Workers Strike(Al Jazeera)](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2016/09/millions-indian-workers-strike-wages-160902131706206.html)

[Real News](http://therealnews.com/t2/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=31&Itemid=74&jumival=17170)

[Indians Staged One of the Largest Strikes in History](https://theintercept.com/2016/09/06/indians-staged-one-of-the-largest-strikes-in-history-but-no-one-on-u-s-cable-news-covered-it/)

200 million is a lot of people. This is about 16% of India's 1.25 billion people; a huge percentage.

It is likely this is the largest strike that has occured when counting the total number of people.

What about as a % of a country's population? Has a larger general strike ever occurred? If so, what % of a country were on strike?  (In order to control for population growth, and the variation in country size, it is the % of the country that was on strike).

Answer (score 14):

In the aftermath of the first World War, approximately 12 million German workers ([source in German](https://www.dhm.de/lemo/kapitel/weimarer-republik/innenpolitik/generalstreik)) out of a [population of 62 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Census_in_Germany#1871_-_1945_German_Empire) went on a general strike to protest the [Kapp Putsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapp_Putsch). This is a slightly higher percentage, 19% of the population compared to 16% from your example. But it was a political strike, not one for traditional economic aims.

I don't know if there were even larger strikes.

Answer (score 13):

The [French General Strike of May 1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_1968_events_in_France) is a likely contender with [around 10 million](https://libcom.org/library/general-strike-france-1968-factory-factory-account) on strike out of a then population of [about 51.2 million](https://countryeconomy.com/demography/population/france?year=1968), or about **19.5% of the total population**. This represented about two-thirds of the total workforce. Some sources put the number as high as 11 million (approx. 21.5% of the population).

[image]

*[L'Aurore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Aurore_(newspaper_founded_1944)) was a French centre-right newspaper which included among its writers several members of the [Académie française](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise). This (weekend) edition is dated **25 & 26 May 1968** and has the sub-heading "**mais 10 millions de Francais sont toujours en greve**". Image source: [cadeauretro.com](http://www.cadeauretro.com/ctrle.php?jour=25&mois=05&annee=1968&codel=%20&country_code=)*

The figure of 10 million is the most widely given, and was quoted by publications at both ends of the political spectrum. The article *[General Strike: France 1968 - A factory by factory account](https://libcom.org/library/general-strike-france-1968-factory-factory-account)* gives figures which show how the numbers increased during May 1968:

> From a few hundred strikers on 14th May at the Sud-Aviation air craft
>   factory in Nantes the strike spread rapidly: 2 million strikers by
>   18th May, 9 million by 24th May, reaching nearly 10 million two days
>   later.

The *[Historical Dictionary of France](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Historical_Dictionary_of_France.html?id=JVIRzOWyqUAC&redir_esc=y)* also gives 9 million for 24th May, but doesn't give a number after that.

A *Journal of Labor Economics* (Univ. of Chicago, 2008) article, *[Vive la Re´volution! Long-Term
Educational Returns of 1968 to the Angry Students](https://www.parisschoolofeconomics.eu/docs/maurin-eric/jole-1968.proof.pdf)* (pdf) says

> Over 10 million French workers were involved in the strikes—roughly
>   two-thirds of the French workforce.

This 2015 undergraduate thesis, *[“Peace Capital”: American Media 's Coverage of May 1968 in Paris](https://scholarworks.uvm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.co.uk/&httpsredir=1&article=1097&context=hcoltheses)* (pdf) gives the highest number:

> Over 11 million workers went on strike during May, which totaled over
>   20% of the population.

The figure of 11 million is also given by Wikipedia's [May 1968 events in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_1968_events_in_France).

Comment: can't beat french at this

Answer (score 4):

The general strike in October-November 1956 Hungary was total in the sense that the strike committee (Central Workers Council Greater Budapest & constituent federative bodies) authorised the continued operation of media, medical and food services under their control; and, in that the Soviet Union enslaved railway workers.